# The Gas of Mystery, What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm the thing you would love

Yet I was a murderer by the millions

I was a poison of the 1900's

Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals

My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer

What am I?

Hint:

> Read the title. Why didn't I just put What am I?

Hint 2:

> Don't take the last line literally!

Comment: I can't parse the last line very well ... is that deliberate?

Comment: Yes, Yes it is the way it is supposed to be

Comment: I was a poison **on** the 1900's? Typo or deliberate?

Comment: All deliberate except for the last one

Comment: Including the "massage" one? I can't imagine what massaging blood would be like.

Comment: Speaking as somebody with a chemistry background, chlorine is about the **worst** answer that fits the riddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been too long so I will answer my own question that has been unanswered for 10 months.

Answer:

> Mustard gas

I'm the thing you would love

> Curing cancer, starts with mustard...

Yet I was a murderer by the millions

> Killed millions of people during wars and battles

I was a poison of the 1900's

> It was a poison developed in the 1900's

Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals

> It help cure cancer

My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer

> Not only it destroys cancer cells, it can destroy white blood cells

Comment: Given how well the other answers fit your clues, maybe it would be fitting to award the reputation to the best-fitting answer that wasn't the one you were thinking of.

Answer (score 6):

My fourth attempt:

> CHLORINE.

*I'm the thing you would love*

> I'm not sure about this bit (though "love chlorine" yields [4 million hits on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?complete=0&hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=love+chlorine&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=2) :-p )

*I was a murderer by the millions 

I was a poison on the 1900's*

> Chlorine gas was the famous poison gas used to kill millions in WWI ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine#Use_as_a_weapon)). 
>  *Gas! Gas! Quick, boys! – An ecstasy of fumbling*

*Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals*

> Chlorine chemistry is essential to more than 93% of prescription pharmaceuticals sold in the US ([ref](http://chlorine.americanchemistry.com/Chlorine-Benefits/Health-and-Safety/Chlorine-and-Medicine.html)).

*My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer*

> I'm not sure about this line yet.

---

### Previous attempt(s)

(I removed the first possibility since I don't think it's killed millions of people.)

> Mustard gas *aka* sulphur mustard.

*I'm the thing you would love*

> I'm not sure about this bit.

*I was a murderer by the millions 

I was a poison on the 1900's*

> Mustard gas was used in the trenches in WWI and killed millions ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_mustard#Use)).

*Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals*

> Sulphur mustard is now used as a cancer chemotherapy drug ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_mustard#Development_of_the_first_chemotherapy_drug)).

*My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer*

> Maybe a reference to the fact that sulphur mustard kills white blood cells?

Comment: You are so dang close!

Comment: @PythonMaster Which possibility is close?

Comment: I can't give that away!

Comment: Fair enough :-) I'm guessing the second one, given your comment on Aggie's answer.

Comment: @PythonMaster Any joy?

Comment: Nope. I lost joy

Comment: Never mind, you got that right! :-)

Comment: @PythonMaster Is chlorine right? But that's been there for almost 2 weeks!

Comment: No, it was Mustard Gas. But chlorine is an excellent alternate.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this quite fits but there are not many remaining toxic substances that have killed millions.

> You are **[cyanide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanide)** for the following reasons

I'm the thing you would love

> People enjoy foods like cassava, lima beans and almonds which contain substances that release cyanide. Pits and seeds of apricots, apples, and peaches, may also have substantial amounts of chemicals which are metabolized to cyanide. But the edible parts of these plants contain much lower amounts of these chemicals.

Yet I was a murderer by the millions, I was a poison on the 1900's

> Deliberate cyanide poisoning of humans has occurred many times throughout history.  Most significantly, hydrogen cyanide released from pellets of Zyklon-B was used extensively in the systematic mass murders of the Holocaust. Poisoning by hydrogen cyanide gas within a gas chamber is one method of executing a condemned prisoner.

Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals

> The cyanide compound, [sodium nitroprusside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_nitroprusside), is primarily used as a [vasodilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasodilation) (to relax the muscle cells of blood vessels). By 1955, data on its safety during short-term use in patients with severe hypertension had become available. Despite this, it was not approved by the US FDA until 1974 for the treatment of severe hypertension. By 1993, its popularity had grown such that total sales in the US had totalled US$2 million.

My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer

> As described above - a vasodilator, a poison

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of, and I dismissed it. You make a good case though.

Comment: Nope but good alternate!

Answer (score 4):

This is a second answer because I think my other answer (cyanide) also fits the clues - but I could be biased ;-)

The gas of mystery is:

> **[hydrogen sulfide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide)**.  It could be called a mystery gas because, at elevated concentrations, the **sense of smell disappears** often together with awareness of the danger.

I'm the thing you would love:

> People enjoy **sulfur springs** or hot springs which may contain low levels of hydrogen sulfide.

Yet I was a murderer by the millions:

> Hydrogen sulfide has been implicated in several **mass extinctions** that have occurred in the Earth's past, in particular the Permian-Triassic extinction event 252 million years ago.

I was a poison of the 1900's:

> Hydrogen sulfide was used by the British Army as a **chemical weapon** during World War I, when other gases were in short supply.

Then a revolutionary medicine in the hospitals:

> **Hydrogen sulfide therapy** is used to reduce damage and complications following a heart attack. This treatment causes relaxation of the smooth muscle cells of blood vessels and promotes blood flow.

My other use a massage to your blood, the other the killer:

> first - to relax muscle cells of blood vessels and second - a very poisonous gas.

Comment: The correct answer has already been posted! PythonMaster confirmed it [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/the-gas-of-mystery-what-am-i#comment32543_10106).

Comment: Bleach maybe? I didn't really work out the "love" line for either of them.

Answer (score -1):

Answer?

> Carbon Dioxide

The thing you would love?

> Oxygen